# How to change background color in TextInputs with icons?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I have a react-native-paper TextInput with a right icon that I want to change background color, but the background behind the icon doesn't change.

It seems like there is a layer behind the TextInput so when changing the TextInput Background and this element cover the whole layer behind there is no problem, but when an icon is added (left or right) the icon pushes the TextInput element a little bit to the side revealing part of the below layer that has the background color I'm trying to remove.

Here in this image you can see two TextInputs both of them I added the backgroundColor property to make them white, but the one below has an icon to the right, behind the icon is the original TextInput background color.

[TextInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abw1n.png)

Making the icon background color white looks as follow:
[When I add backgroundColor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bygEI.png)

I've tried changing background using theme, style and backgroundColor props, but nothing is working so far.

Is there a way to remove the purple background (or make it white)?

here is what my code looks like right now:

```
        <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      mode="flat"
      autoCapitalize="none"
      secureTextEntry={showPassword ? false : true}
      label="Contraseña"
      value={password}
      backgroundColor="white"
      onChangeText={value => setPassword(value)}
      textColor="black"
      underlineColor="rgb(102,102, 102)"
      activeUnderlineColor="rgb(102,102, 102)"
      right={
        <TextInput.Icon
          icon={showPassword ? 'eye' : 'eye-off'}
          size={25}
          onPress={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)}
          style={styles.eyeIcon}
        />
      }
    />
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please add the code and styling for your TextInput and icon so others can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with this, adding the theme property and change color in surfaceVariant prop, like this

```js
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    mode="flat"
    autoCapitalize="none"
    secureTextEntry={showPassword ? false : true}
    label="Contraseña"
    value={password}
    onChangeText={value => setPassword(value)}
    textColor="black"
    underlineColor="rgb(102,102, 102)"
    activeUnderlineColor="rgb(102,102, 102)"
    theme={{
        ...DefaultTheme,
        colors: {
            surfaceVariant: 'white',
        },
    }}
    right={
        <TextInput.Icon
            icon={showPassword ? 'eye' : 'eye-off'}
            size={25}
            onPress={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)}
            style={styles.eyeIcon}
        />
    }
/>
```